# Inserting New Object Into Specific Array Index

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

There is a  MongoDB collection, which is an array of objects being returned from an Angular Resource.

```
[{_id: "565ee3582b8981f015494cef", button: "", reference: "", text: "", title: "", …}, 
 {_id: "565ee3582b8981f015494cf0", button: "", reference: "", text: "", title: "", …}]
```

I have to allow the user to insert an object into any index of the array, and save to MongoDB through Mongoose.

```
var object = {
    button: "",
    image: {},
    reference: "",
    text: "",
    title: "",
};
```

I understand how to push the object to the end of the array, but how can I specify what index for the insertion?

So far, thinking of first creating the object:

```
Slide.create(object, function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Then using an update method to update the position in the array:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have the following document in your collection

```js
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("565eed81abab97411fbe32fc"),
        "docs" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "565ee3582b8981f015494cef",
                        "button" : "",
                        "reference" : "",
                        "text" : "",
                        "title" : ""
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "565ee3582b8981f015494cf0",
                        "button" : "",
                        "reference" : "",
                        "text" : "",
                        "title" : ""
                }
        ]
}
```

You need to use [`$position`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/position/) operator to specify the location in the array at which the [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#up._S_push) operator insert elements and as mentioned in the documentation:

> To use the `$position` modifier, it must appear with the [`$each`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/each/#up._S_each) modifier.

Demo

```js
var object = {
    button: "",
    image: {},
    reference: "",
    text: "",
    title: "",
};

db.slide.update({/*filter*/}, 
    { '$push': { 'docs': { '$each': [object], '$position': 1 } }
})
```

You newly updated document will look like this:

```js
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("565eed81abab97411fbe32fc"),
        "docs" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "565ee3582b8981f015494cef",
                        "button" : "",
                        "reference" : "",
                        "text" : "",
                        "title" : ""
                },
                {
                        "button" : "",
                        "image" : {

                        },
                        "reference" : "",
                        "text" : "",
                        "title" : ""
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "565ee3582b8981f015494cf0",
                        "button" : "",
                        "reference" : "",
                        "text" : "",
                        "title" : ""
                }
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var object = {
    button: "",
    image: {},
    reference: "",
    text: "",
    title: "",
};

arr.splice(2, 0, object);
```

Will push the `object` in the array at `2nd index` i.e. it will be the third element.

Comment: I need to update this object to MongoDB... will clarify question. TY